# Laravel getNameAttribute not working with search

Tags: php, laravel

I have `Account` model, and inside I have this method:

```
public function getNameAttribute()
{
    if(\App::getLocale() == 'en')
        return $this->attributes['foreign_name'];
    else
        return $this->attributes['name'];
}
```

In the index page it's working.  If the locale is `en` the name will be the `foreign_name`, like this picture:

[image]

But I have search method, and this is the code:

```
public static function search_and_select($keyword)
{
    $keyword = Helper::clean_keyword($keyword);
    $data = Account::where
    ('number','like','%'.$keyword.'%')->
    orWhere('name','like','%'.$keyword.'%')->
    limit(30)->
    get(['user_id','number','name']);
    if(count($data) == 0)
        return Helper::no_result();
    return [$data,['number','name']];       
}
```

If I try to search about anything I get this error:

```
message: "Undefined index: foreign_name"
    1: {,…}
class: "App\Models\Account"
file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php"
function: "getNameAttribute"
line: 465
type: "->"
2: {,…}
class: "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model"
file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php"
function: "mutateAttribute"
line: 479
type: "->"
```

But if I change:

```
return $this->attributes['foreign_name'];
```

to

```
return $this->attributes['id']; // or any integer field in the accounts table
```

It's working without problem.

With Laravel 6 it was working like that with me but now I get this error. Any help here?

This is the full model code:

```
namespace App\Models;
use Helper;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Auth;
class Account extends Model
{
    use Notifiable,SoftDeletes;
    protected $table = 'accounts';
    protected $fillable = 
    [
        'number',
        'name',
        'foreign_name',
        'main_account_id',
        'user_id',
        'account_state_id',
        'note',
        'created_by','deleted_by'
    ];
    public function get_created_by()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User','id','created_by');
    }
    public function get_deleted_by()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User','id','deleted_by');
    }
    public function get_user_id()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\User','id','user_id');
    }
    public static function search_scope($keyword)
    {
        $keyword = Helper::clean_keyword($keyword);
        $data = Account::where
        ('number','like','%'.$keyword.'%')->
        orWhere('name','like','%'.$keyword.'%')->
        limit(30)->
        get(['id','number','name']);
        if(count($data) == 0)
            return Helper::no_result();
        return [$data,['number','name']];
    }
    public static function search_and_select($keyword)
    {
        $keyword = Helper::clean_keyword($keyword);
        $data = Account::where
        ('number','like','%'.$keyword.'%')->
        orWhere('name','like','%'.$keyword.'%')->
        limit(30)->
        get(['user_id','number','name']);
        if(count($data) == 0)
            return Helper::no_result();
        return [$data,['number','name']];       
    }
    public function getNameAttribute()
    {
        if(\App::getLocale() == 'en')
            return $this->attributes['foreign_name'];
        else
            return $this->attributes['name'];
    }
}
```

this is the search and select html code

```
<search_and_select>
<div slot='search_and_select' slot-scope="{change_keyword,results,no_result,chose_data,keyword,hidden_id,chose_first_value}">
    <div class="container" style='width:40vw;'>
            <input class="form-control {{$search_and_select}}" type="text" @keyup='change_keyword($event.target.value,"{{$type}}")' @keyup.enter='chose_first_value()' v-model='keyword' :run="!keyword ? keyword = '{{$value}}' : true" {{$required ?? null}}>
            <input type='hidden' v-model='hidden_id' name='{{$search_and_select}}' :run="!hidden_id ? hidden_id = '{{$hidden_id}}' : true"/>
        <ul v-if='no_result' class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">{{trans('language.no_result')}}</li>
        </ul>
        <ul v-if='results' class="list-group">
            <li v-for='result in results'><input class='results' @click='chose_data(result.id,result.number,result.name)' @keyup.enter='chose_data(result.id,result.number,result.name)'  type='text' :value='result.number+" "+result.name' /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the include file

```
@include(
    'treats.create_search_and_select',
    [
        'search_and_select' => $search_and_selects[$key],
        'value' => $search_and_selects_values[$key],
        'hidden_id' => $search_and_selects_hidden_ids[$key],
        'type' => $search_and_selects_type[$key],
        'required' => $search_and_selects_requireds[$key],
        'language' => $search_and_selects_languages[$key],
        'hint' => $search_and_selects_hints[$key],
        'policy' => $search_and_selects_policies[$key],
        'show_type' => $search_and_selects_show_types[$key],
        'rank' => $search_and_selects_ranks[$key],
    ]
)
```

and this is the console errors
[image]
[image]
and this is how i call search_and_select

```
public function search_and_select(Request $request)
{
    if(!Gate::allows($request['model'].'.view'))
        return Helper::not_auth();
    $model = Model::where('name',$request['model'])->firstOrFail();
    $model_name = '\App\Models\\'.$model['model'];
    $data = $model_name::search_and_select($request['keyword']);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: `dd($this->attributes)` and check if there is a `foreign_name` attribute in there. Its telling you that it doesn't exist. `id` works because it exists.

Comment: it is exists and this is image https://i.postimg.cc/C5Z5tCSQ/Capture.png

Comment: did you `dd` it right above `this->attributes['foreign_name']`? Also, try `return $this->foreign_name`

Comment: i did return $this->foreign_name i gat same error

Comment: Please, update your answer and post the whole `Account` model.

Comment: ive update the post

Comment: try adding 'foreign_name' to `get(['user_id','number','name']);`

Comment: ive  already dnoe that before but still get message: "Undefined index: foreign_name"

Comment: how do you use this static method `search_and_select`? in controller? post full code please. and also post full error backtrace, it would be helpful.

Comment: ive update the post

Comment: Is `foreign_name` not null column in table? Also seed data again and check all data has value in that column and print just `foreign_name` directly in foreach loop in to check all model has `foreign_name`

Comment: can you please try to add     `protected $casts = [
        'foreign_name' => 'string', 'name' => 'string',
    ];` to your `Account` Model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of your line

```
get(['user_id','number','name'])
```

Which asks to fetch only these columns. You need to add foreign_name to this array and make it

```
get(['user_id','number','name', 'foreign_name'])
```

According to Laravel [reference](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_get), get function accepts a list of columns.

**Same applies at other functions**